# Having difficulty posting to php using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What I'm trying to do is to set a php session variable after a button is clicked. I know that to do this I'm going to have to combine jquery, ajax, and php but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas? Thanks!

This is my jquery:

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
        //set session variable
        $.ajax({
            url: "checkout.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                "item1": "sold"
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            success: function(data){
                $("#picture1").css("opacity", "0.5");
                $("#button1").css("opacity", "0.5");
                $("#item1").css("opacity", "0.5");
                alert('data:' + data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
            } 
        });
    });
```

And here is my PHP:

```
session_start();
var_dump($_POST);
if($_POST["item1"] === "sold"){
$_SESSION["item1"] = $_POST["item1"];
echo json_encode('ok');
}
```

Comment: can you let us know what is the issue? Any live url

Comment: The issue is that nothing is in the $_POST array on the other side(php). I'm also getting an error that says undefined index which makes sense since the $_POST['item'] variable isn't set.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is on your if statement, you're using the is identical operator, try using the is equal to one. (You're using === instead of ==).

Comment: I changed it with no luck

Comment: I suggest using Firebug and inspecting your post requests, make sure everything is going as it should be, this way we can figure out where the issue relies, on the frontend or the backend

Comment: Sorry guys, I had a hell of a week so I'm just getting on now. On firebug it's telling me syntaxError: expected expression 'got'. Any idea what that means?

Comment: Meaning something is wrong with your javascript syntax, is that the whole error ? on your website where this script is used, do inspect elements and look at the javascript messages, it will tell you the full error + the line number